# ¿Cómo puedo separar los caracteres de un solo string para que formen strings independientes? en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Si tengo en una lista el string '111111' o 'hola', como puedo separar los caracteres y que en la lista quede ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1, '1'] o ['h', 'o', 'l', 'a']??

(si tiene algo que ver, no puedo utilizar ninguna biblioteca)

Comment: Bienvenido user209312 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: `[x for x in el-string-en-cuestion]`

Comment: O bien, `list('Hola')`

Answer (score 4):

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo en python

La más fea sería ir recorriendo el string y agregándolo a la lista:

```
v = "11111"
output = []
for i in v:
    output.append(i)
```

También podemos hacer uso del list comprehension de python:

```
v = "11111"
output = [i for i in v]
```

O directamente python nos permite convertir un tipo de dato string a list

```
output = list(v)
```

Comment: +1 por el estilo conciso y preciso.

Comment: Otras 2 maneras: `output = [*v]` ([Python 3.5 o superior](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)). La otra forma: `output = []` y luego `output.extend(v)`